# Android:problem in displaying the progressbar dialog?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog, progress-bar

in my app i trying to display a progressbar for a time taken for a function to complete its execution and  dismiss it after the function has completed its execution ...

my code definition is as follows :

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case PROCESS: {
                ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                dialog.setTitle("Indeterminate");
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait while loading...");
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                return dialog;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }




showDialog(PROCESS);
doFunction();
dismissDialog(PROCESS);
```

and for some reason the processdialog is not is not displayed...

can some one help me out here pls....
is there any other way to do it ...

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function takes some time to process, use an async task

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
             pd = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),"", "Sending Image ...", true);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            doFunction();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }.execute();
```

Secondly setting it to indeterminate means you will only see a circle thingy.

You should set the [progress style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgressStyle%28int%29) to `STYLE_HORIZONTAL`

Comment: i have tried this but i am getting an error like....           'android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application' ....    can u help me out man....